# Using Api or Query to communicate with the sql server database

Tags: c#

My friends, I have a program under Windows that is designed with C# and SQL database. My server system is far from the client and I have to connect to SQL from a static IP over the Internet. A question that occurred to me is whether to use a query or api to connect to the database and operations. Query is easier to work with and doesn't need setup, and its speed is high, for example, when we want to load the entire list of users. Is there a problem if I make a query over the Internet? Or is there a taste... I would appreciate it if you could give me some advice. The number of clients who use this software should be a maximum of 10 people.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_user(id, name) values(1,'ali')", con);